# The choice between 'will' and 'would'

Tags: grammaticality

"I will not accept the truth that I will be jealous if you have a boyfriend unless you accept the truth that you will be jealous if I have a girlfriend," said Phil.

Is this sentence correct or should I use 'would' in the places where I have used 'will'?
Or should I use 'would' only when there is 'had' in the places of 'have'?

*confused*

Comment: See also: [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

> 1) "I will not accept the truth that I will be jealous if you have a boyfriend unless you accept the truth that you will be jealous if I have a girlfriend"

and

> 2) "I will not accept the truth that I would be jealous if you had a boyfriend unless you accept the truth that you would be jealous if I had a girlfriend"

both qualify as standard English usage. They differ in the degree to which they describe a hypothetical situation. Both versions describe a potential situation rather than an actual one, but that situation is further removed from the present in version 2) than it is in version 1).

All that being said, I found your query sentence difficult to understand without reading it more than once. It would benefit from being simplified -- for instance:

> 3) "I won't admit that I'll get jealous if you have a boyfriend unless you admit that you'll get jealous if I have a girlfriend"

Comment: @ Eric, I'll go with your third sentence. Sounds great. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between will and would. With will, you state a fact about what you plan to do. With would, you place conditions on what you plan to do.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know by using "would" you describe a situation ( conditional clause type 2) that is "very unlikely to happen". Also you can use it to talk about the result of "an imagined situation".